# Limit the post method, excluding a url in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, methods, limit, nextcloud

I am using NextCloud to store some personal files. For security purposes, I decided to limit accessing post and couple other methods for my visitors.

The issue is if I want to share a file, and makes it password protected, it is also necessary to have 'post' access beside 'get' access for a visitor.

A shared password protected URL in NextCloud is sth like this:

```
https://MyDomainName.ltd/index.php/s/KwDGEW42xNfExA/authenticate/showShare
```

Here is my code:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/index.php/s/$1 allow-it



<Limit POST >



Order allow,deny

allow from MyIP [OR]
allow from MySecondIp [OR]
allow from MyThirdIP [OR]

Allow from env=allow-it


</Limit>
```

I want to allow post method for everything comes after /index.php/s/ beside full access for my own ip addresses that I currently have.

This (/index.php/s/) part of my url is not a real directory, so I can't go inside the directory to add my rules.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my own issue changing the code to:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/index.php/s/* allow-it



<Limit POST >



order deny,allow
 deny from all

allow from MyFirstIP [OR]
allow from MySecondIp [OR]

allow from env=allow-it


</Limit>
```

If someone else has the same concern, you only need to give head and get access for downloading a file. Everything else can be limited using the same method.